# Kotlin activity not found in certain devices

Tags: android, exception, android-activity, kotlin

I saw a few people having the same problem, with Kotlin files seemed not to be included in the .apk file, throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution exception during runtime.

Following another Stackoverflow answers steps, I thought I managed to solve this issue, but it still happens in some devices (BQ Aquaris V7.1.1) every second build. I mean, if I build the .apk and get this issue, it will disappear if I build the .apk file and install it again.

So it occurs only in a few phones and buiding the .apk file again solves it.

Any clue why this is happenning?

Given that it works fine in most of the devices I guess my Gradle settings, Kotlin, and Android Studio version are ok.

Thanks in advace.

Here is the log thrown in the devices in which the activity is not found:

> Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Didn't find class
>   "com.project.myapp.kotlin.MyKotlinActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/com.project.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.project.myapp-1/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/com.project.myapp-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>
> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/project/myapp/kotlin/MyKotlinActivity;
>   com.project.myapp.main.HomeActivity.openMyKotlinActivity
>   (HomeActivity.java:281)
>   com.project.myapp.main.HomeFragment.openMyKotlinActivity
>   (HomeFragment.java:622)
>   com.project.myapp.main.HomeFragment.onCreateView
>   (HomeFragment.java:205)
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2354)
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState
>   (FragmentManager.java:1419)
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState
>   (FragmentManager.java:1740)
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState
>   (FragmentManager.java:1809)
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps
>   (BackStackRecord.java:799)
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps
>   (FragmentManager.java:2580)
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether
>   (FragmentManager.java:2367)
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute
>   (FragmentManager.java:2322)
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions
>   (FragmentManager.java:2229)
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange
>   (FragmentManager.java:3221)
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated
>   (FragmentManager.java:3171)
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated
>   (FragmentController.java:192)
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart
>   (FragmentActivity.java:560)
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart
>   (AppCompatActivity.java:177)
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart
>   (Instrumentation.java:1237) android.app.Activity.performStart
>   (Activity.java:6268) android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2379)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2476) android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11
>   (ActivityThread.java) android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
>   (ActivityThread.java:1344) android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
>   (Handler.java:102) android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5417)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (ZygoteInit.java:726) com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Probably a bug in those devices. Post the full stacktrace of the exception